# Removed Linux Kernels are still showing up in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have removed several deprecated 3.16 kernels, however one is still showing up in GRUB and Ubuntu is booting using that kernel. When I run `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic` the image is not listed. When I run `sudo update-grub` it finds the Kernel in `/boot` and adds it to the list of Kernels to run.

Can I just delete this file? How do I remove this kernel, so that Ubuntu runs under 3.13?

`ls /boot` screenshot:

[image: ls /boot]

`dpkg -l | grep` screeshot:

[image: dpkg -l]

Comment: Use the command `dpkg -S /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-51-generic` instead.

Comment: Here's the output:

dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-51-generic

Comment: Use the GRUB menu to boot into a 3.13 kernel before trying to remove the last 3.16 kernel.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that already several times. When I attempt to delete the image it errors out with 'Unable to locate package <header>'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can remove the files listed in grub, but not with dpkg from the /boot folder.

List kernels:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

Remove the unused kernel with:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-123-generic --verbose-versions
```

If any kernel is still listed in **grub** - but not with **dpkg**, then you can remove them from the /boot library (put them in a temp folder if you prefer seat belt while driving). Then regenerate grub entry

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove them with `sudo purge-old-kernels` (from `byobu` package), not but hand.
And execute `sudo apt-get autoremove` afterwards for removing obsolete packages (headers and images).

FIY, you can save this script anywhere and run as root:

```
$ cat `which purge-old-kernels`

#!/bin/sh
#
#    purge-old-kernels - remove old kernel packages
#    Copyright (C) 2012 Dustin Kirkland <kirkland@ubuntu.com>
#
#    Authors: Dustin Kirkland <kirkland@ubuntu.com>
#             Kees Cook <kees@ubuntu.com>
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, version 3 of the License.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# Ensure we're running as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: This script must run as root.  Hint..." 1>&2
    echo "  sudo $0 $@" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# NOTE: This script will ALWAYS keep the currently running kernel
# NOTE: Default is to keep 2 more, user overrides with --keep N
KEEP=2
# NOTE: Any unrecognized option will be passed straight through to apt
APT_OPTS=
while [ ! -z "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        --keep)
            # User specified the number of kernels to keep
            KEEP="$2"
            shift 2
        ;;
        *)
            APT_OPTS="$APT_OPTS $1"
            shift 1
        ;;
    esac
done

# Build our list of kernel packages to purge
CANDIDATES=$(ls -tr /boot/vmlinuz-* | head -n -${KEEP} | grep -v "$(uname -r)$" | cut -d- -f2- | awk '{print "linux-image-" $0 " linux-headers-" $0}' )
for c in $CANDIDATES; do
    dpkg-query -s "$c" >/dev/null 2>&1 && PURGE="$PURGE $c"
done

if [ -z "$PURGE" ]; then
    echo "No kernels are eligible for removal"
    exit 0
fi

apt $APT_OPTS remove --purge $PURGE
```

Comment: Tried..didn't realize it required another package that I don't have. When I ran the command 'sudo purge-old-kernels' I get 'command not found'. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: It seems  that you are not familiar with apt-get. You should install `byobu` package with `sudo apt-get install byobu`.

Comment: I should have clarified. I don't want to install an additional package just to handle this one instance. There should be a way to clear this out without needing an additional package.

Comment: OK, you can save contents of this script to location where you want and use it from here.